# Can't redirect to a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to redirect to the answer path.

After creating a comment, I have this path

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
        @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
        @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comment])
        @comment.writer = current_user.username
        @comment.save
            redirect_to question_answer_url
    end
end
```

However, I get that  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"answers"}. However, I definitely have this method in my answers controller

```
def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.new(params[:comment])
end
```

I've also tried redirect_to question_answer_path([@question, @answer]), however, that isn't working either as it says no route matches (I assume maybe that's too much information?).

I've nested my resources in my routes such as they go as follows question-->answer-->comment

I'm wondering why my redirects aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to the path, without array brackets:

```
redirect_to question_answer_path(@question,@answer)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What's the difference between redirecting in a controller and redirecting in a view? When I use the above format in a  view, I get no such route exists. I have to use question_answer_path([@question, @answer]), and even then, I get the same answer_id for all redirects.

Comment: In a controller you redirect, in a view you link. Redirect happens before rendering a view. After a view has been rendered, you need clickable objects <a href='...'>. You achieve that by typing 
<%= link_to "Your text for the link", question_answer_path(@question,@answer) %>